# Linking php with xhtml

Tags: php, xhtml

Hey guys quick silly question but i cant for the life of me remember how to do it

i have a php file and i want it to link in with a xhtml file so it runs at the start of the page load up, the php it LDAP authentication and i want this to be successful before a user goes to the page

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like

```
require_once('/path/to/your/file.php');
```

Comment: perfect ! i knew it was something simple

Comment: just make sure the xhtml has a .php file extension as you use php code to include the auth file. pls accept my answer if it was helpful to you.

Comment: thanks will do but now when i include that line and change the format to php i get java.io.FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

You mean LDAP authentication using PHP? Look at this example:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/101525-ldap-authentication/

If user is not authenticated, show html form, ask for credentials, if it is authenticated, show your xhtml

Comment: i got the LDAP auth all coded up in PHP and working i just cant remember how to link the php file into the xhtml page